# How to normalize ranked data in scikit learn?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn

I am doing some machine learning and need help with one aspect of my coding. In my training data, I have a number of URLs of webpages and some features for these webpages. I am running TF-IDF on the text of the webpage text to create more features.

One of the features I have extracted is, for each web address, I retrieve the Google Page ranking. This value can be any value in the world,but the lower the rank, "better quality" Google has deemed it to be.

How can I normalize this figure, given that I have 7,000 web addresses and the ranks can vary enormously (www.google.com, for instance, may be ranked #1, while www.bbc.co.uk may be #1,117, other ranks will fall well outside of our 7,000 URLs).

How can I use scikit learn to effectively normalize this data so that it may be used in my machine learning algorithm? I am running a Logistic Regression which is merely trying to predict whether a webpage is "good" or not. The only features I use at the moment are the ones created with my TF-IDF on the webpage text. Ideally I would like to combine these with my page ranking feature in a way that will give me the highest cross-validation score.

Thanks very much!

So we can assume my data is in a TSV of the form :

```
URL GooglePageRank WebsiteText
```

An example of a row :

```
http://www.google.com 1 This would be the text of the google webpage.
```

I wish to normalize my ranking data and use it in my logistic regression. At the moment, I am only using the "WebsiteText" column, running a TF-IDF on it, and plugging that into my Logistic Regression. I want to learn how to combine this column with my normalised GooglePageRank column and use these two columns in my Logistic Regression - how can I do this?

Here is my code thus far :

```
  import numpy as np
  from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')

  print "loading data.."
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2])
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,-1]

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)

  X_all = traindata + testdata
  lentrain = len(traindata)

  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)

  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]

  print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

  print "training on full data"
  rd.fit(X,y)
  pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
  testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
  pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
  pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
  print "submission file created.."
```

**Edit : **

This is what I am currently running -

```
from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
import sklearn.preprocessing
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import pandas as p
loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=',')
print "loading data.."

#load train/test data for TF-IDF -- I know this is bad practice, but keeping it this way for the moment!
traindata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
testdata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])

#load labels
y = np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,-2]

#Load Integer values and append together
AllAlexaInfo = np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,-1]

#make tfidf object
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
                      analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), 
                      use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)
div = DictVectorizer()
X = []
X_all = traindata + testdata
lentrain = len(traindata)
# fit/transform the TfidfVectorizer on the training data
vect = tfv.fit_transform(X_all) #bad practice, but using this for the moment!

for i, alexarank in enumerate(AllAlexaInfo):
    feature_dict = {'alexarank': AllAlexaInfo}
    # get ith row of the tfidf matrix (corresponding to sample)
    row = vect.getrow(i)    

    # filter the feature names corresponding to the sample
    all_words = tfv.get_feature_names()
    words = [all_words[ind] for ind in row.indices] 

    # associate each word (feature) with its corresponding score
    word_score = dict(zip(words, row.data)) 

    # concatenate the word feature/score with the datamining feature/value
    X.append(dict(word_score.items() + feature_dict.items()))

div.fit_transform(X)  # training data based on both Tfidf features and pagerank
sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X = sc.transform(X)
X_test = X_all[lentrain:]
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

print "training on full data"
rd.fit(X,y)
pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
print "submission file created.."
```

This appears to be running forever, also I believe I have a problem with the "alexarank" value not being input correctly - how can I fix this?

Comment: IIRC, you would like to combine features from your TfidfVectorizer with the pagerank value, thus having your logistic regression classfier making a choice based on both the text features and the pagerank value?

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol This is correct, yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, I would perform accordingly:

```
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(
    min_df=3,
    max_features=None,
    strip_accents='unicode',                    
    analyzer='word',
    token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
    ngram_range=(1, 2), 
    use_idf=1,
    smooth_idf=1,
    sublinear_tf=1)
div = DictVectorizer()

X = []

# fit/transform the TfidfVectorizer on the training data
vectors = tfv.fit_transform(traindata)

for i, pagerank in enumerate(pageranks):
    feature_dict = {'pagerank': pagerank}
    # get ith row of the tfidf matrix (corresponding to sample)
    row = vect.getrow(i)    

    # filter the feature names corresponding to the sample
    all_words = tfv.get_feature_names()
    words = [all_words[ind] for ind in row.indices] 

    # associate each word (feature) with its corresponding score
    word_score = dict(zip(words, row.data)) 

    # concatenate the word feature/score with the datamining feature/value
    X.append(dict(word_score.items() + feature_dict.items()))

div.fit_transform(X)  # training data based on both Tfidf features and pagerank
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. In this instance, how are you enumerating over the page ranks? How have you read them in? Your response is very helpful, just struggling to get it running at the moment - I am a beginner at Python so bear with me! :) Thank you :)

Comment: I have updated my question to show the additions I have made to my code using your suggestions. Unfortunately I still cannot get it to run :(

Comment: In your original question, you stated that both the GooglePageRank and the WebsiteText were located in the same row, separated by a tab. In my answer, I assumed you had loaded the pageranks into memory. You could do it (for example) using a list comprehension: ``pageranks = [line.split('\t')[1] for line in my_file]``

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. I am still having some trouble trying to run your code however. I have updated my edit above to show this. I am reading in the PageRank column using pandas, but seem to be getting a `ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df` whenever I try and run this code. Sorry for the nuisance but any help you might be able to give me would be really appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried to increase the ``max_df`` value in the ``TfidfVectorizer`` constructor? Its default value is 1.0

Comment: I have updated my code above reflecting the changes you suggest. It will now run, but it appears to run forever. It has not finished after a full night. Can you tell me what I have done incorrectly? I believe the `AlexaRank` value is being input into my loop incorrectly but I am not sure how to fix this. Can you offer any advice please? :) Thank you :)

Comment: At this point, I really can't do more without the data. You should debug perform a step-by-step debug of your code, eg using ``pdb``. Good luck!